# Widgets centred horizontally and labels to the left of these widgets

Tags: python, pyqt

There are some widgets centred horizontally:

```
class TestWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._init_ui()

    def _init_ui(self):
        edit1_label = QLabel("Edit1")
        edit2_label = QLabel("Edit2")
        edit3_label = QLabel("Edit3")
        edit1 = QLineEdit()
        edit2 = QLineEdit()
        edit3 = QLineEdit()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(edit1)
        layout.addWidget(edit2)
        layout.addWidget(edit3)
        layout.addStretch()

        hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout.addLayout(layout)
        self.setLayout(hlayout)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground)


def _main():
    app = QApplication([''])
    app.setStyleSheet("""
                    TestWidget {
                        min-height: 400px;
                        max-height: 400px;
                        min-width: 600px;
                        max-width: 600px;
                    }
                    TestWidget QLineEdit {
                        min-height: 2em;
                        max-height: 2em;
                        min-width: 20em;
                        max-width: 20em;
                        }
                    """)
w = TestWidget()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

I would like to place labels(edit1_label, edit2_label, edit3_label) to the left of the edits(edit1, edit2, edit3). But the edits should be centred horizontally on the form. How could it be implemented?

Updated: Added example graphic(Please note QLineEdits are centred horizontally on the form):

[image: example graphic]

Wrong result:
[image]

Comment: In short you want to place the QLabels on the side of QLineEdits without decentralizing them

Comment: Yes, you are right, @eyllanesc

Comment: You might want to look into a QFormLayout.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but it might help:

```
def _init_ui(self):
    mainLayout = QGridLayout()
    mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
    mainLayout.setColumnStretch(3, 1)

    edit1_label = QLabel("Edit1")
    edit1 = QLineEdit()

    mainLayout.addWidget(edit1_label, 1, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(edit1, 1, 2)

    edit2_label = QLabel("Edit2")
    edit2 = QLineEdit()

    mainLayout.addWidget(edit2_label, 2, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(edit2, 2, 2)

    edit3_label = QLabel("Edit3")
    edit3 = QLineEdit()

    mainLayout.addWidget(edit3_label, 3, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(edit3, 3, 2)

    mainLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

    self.setLayout(mainLayout)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground)
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this isn't what I want.

Comment: So maybe improve your question such that we know what you want :)

Comment: I have added example graphic.

Comment: I edited my answer: I changed layout to `Grid` and added some `stretch`.

Comment: I've re-checked this. Unfortunately, QLineEdits are not in the centre of the window. Please see attached "Wrong result" image.

Comment: It says `The image "https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAPeT.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`

Comment: Now I understand what you want to achieve. However, I don't believe relative positioning could handle this. You could try absolute positioning (see [this](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/layoutmanagement/) example using `move` method), but it's not very generic solution. If you need more help, let me know :)